# Read words that are bold and Italic from word document using c#

Tags: c#, ms-word

I have no idea how to separate bold and italicized words from normal words.

Can any one suggest how to identify bold and italic words using C#?

Here is what I have so far:

```
foreach (Word.Paragraph objparagraph in document.Paragraphs)
{
    string sLine = objparagraph.Range.Text;
    if (sLine.Contains(Font.Bold && Font.Italic))
    { 

    }
}
```

Comment: Are you able to read text from a word document at all? That's step one.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can show code that you have that *doesn't* distinguish between bold and italicized words.  We'll help from there.

Comment: You might find this helpful. As others have mentioned, we can't help much without knowing what you have done. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.find_members%28v=office.14%29.aspx

Comment: @Blorgbeard Yeah I could read... :)

Comment: @KirkWoll I have updated the question ...Is that the right way??

Comment: I've done project with similar objectives and had consistent success with OpenXml.  You can get it through NuGet or here: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5124

Comment: @KirkWoll thanks for posting your code! The code you posted definitely won't work though - a `string` cannot contain a `Font`. I don't know the correct way to do it, but now you have posted code, someone else will probably be able to fix it for you :)

Comment: @Blorgbeard I will split sentencewith " " (Spaces) and then check for bold and Italics...Thanks for ur comment

Comment: @KirkWoll ... Can some one suggest me something?? please..!!

Comment: @chessofnerd can u help me now..?? I have posted my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I haven't been able to test this code so I make no promises that it will work! I provide this but want to be upfront that my answer is AFAIK!

That said, what you are currently doing won't work because you are converting a *Paragraph* object (that contains the needed bold and italic information) to a *string* object (that does *not* contain the bold or italic information. That is, you are loosing the bold/italic information before you have a chance to test if it is there! Instead of using the .Range.Text properties, you want to just use the .Range property. The code will look something like this:

```
foreach (Word.Paragraph objparagraph in document.Paragraphs)
{
    int TRUE_CODE = 1;     // I do NOT know if this is correct, it could be another number!

    Range rWords = objparagraph.Range.Text;
    foreach (Range word in rWords.Words
        if (word.Bold == TRUE_CODE)
        { 
             // handle bold case
        }
        if (word.Italic == TRUE_CODE)
             // handle italic case
        }
    }
}
```

As I have not tested this code, be aware that it might require tweaking to get it right. Particularly, you would think word.Bold and word.Italic would return true or false, but they don't. Instead, they return an integer which represents one of three things.

```
true - the word is bold (or italic)
false - the word is _not_ bold (or italic)
wdUndefined - the word is something else (combination, etc.)
```

(see the below link for the documentation on this) The problem is, I don't know what integer goes with each category. In the code snippet above, I have assumed that 1 maps to true, but this might not be correct! Hopefully it is enough to get you started though. Happy coding!

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.range.bold.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1

Comment: The TRUE_CODE must be -1 
and Range rWords = objparagraph.Range;  Only not .Text
Thanks u It's working properly...